# Is there a way to tell when a computed property has been inserted in the DOM with Ember?

Tags: ember.js

I have a computed property that acts as formatter.  Example fiddle to show basic functionality here
, http://jsfiddle.net/mlienau/xSkyd/2/.

I haven't implemented this functionality in the example, but the end user of this can remove terms by dragging them out, using draggable from jquery-ui .  I was accomplishing this using a jquery live on `mouseover` of the  element, but on ipad it doesn't work.  Adding `touchstart` to live event is a hack because the user has to touch it once, before they can drag it out.

So my main question is: Is there a way to determine when a computed property has been inserted into the DOM like there is with view and didInsertElement, so I can set up the draggable handle there?  Also, I am aware of some non-ideal ember practices in the example.  Thanks!